# apply sparql with two variable and return the results in java variable

Tags: java, sparql, jena

in jena I can write a program that can run this query and print out the results

```
select distinct  ?class where {?s rdf:type ?class }
```

how can modify the program to apply this query and return the results in java array

```
select distinct  ?s ?class where {?s rdf:type ?class }
```

the program

```
private void runQuer(String query, Model model) {
    //create Buffer
    StringBuffer queryStr = new StringBuffer();
    // Establish Prefixes
    queryStr.append("PREFIX esco" + ": <" + defaultNameSpace + "> ");
    queryStr.append("PREFIX rdfs" + ": <" + "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" + "> ");
    queryStr.append("PREFIX rdf" + ": <" + "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" + "> ");
    //Now add query
    queryStr.append(query);
    Query queryExec = QueryFactory.create(queryStr.toString());
    QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(queryExec, model);
    try {
    ResultSet response = qexec.execSelect();

    while( response.hasNext()){
        QuerySolution soln = response.nextSolution();
        RDFNode name = soln.get("?class");
        if( name != null ){
            System.out.println(  name.toString() );
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("No Friends found!");
                }
            } finally { qexec.close();}


}
```

Comment: Ehm, why not just create a Java `ArrayList` and add the items? I don't understand why this is too complicated for you given that this is too obvious...but looks like you copy pasted the code from some other example. Anyways, Java basics - should be possible for you, I'm sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like the values as an array, in particular, then there are several ways to get it.

```
final QuerySolution[] solutionsAsArray;
try(final QueryExecution exec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model)) {
  final Iterable<QuerySolution> execAsIterable = exec::execSelect;
  solutionsAsArray = StreamSupport
      .stream(execAsIterable.spliterator(), false)
      .toArray(count -> new QuerySolution[count]);
}
```

If possible, you may wish to avoid patterns like this. A good general design will treat the number of results from a sparql query as an infinite stream, and not attempt to retain all of the results.

Note that if you want to retain some java object rather than the `QuerySolution`, you can use the [`Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method to transform your solution before aggregation into an array.

Comment: [`ResultSetFormatter.toList(rs)`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/ResultSetFormatter.html#toList-org.apache.jena.query.ResultSet-)

Comment: @AKSW I wasn't aware of that method. Way easier to get a list/stream that way.